# uilabel crash when having a lot of text content

Tags: text, crash, uilabel

I meet a problem when I set a UILabel with large content, like 20,000 words. And I calculate the size of the UILabel by this method:

```c
 CGSize labelSize = [myLabel.text sizeWithFont:myLabel.text.font 
                                                            constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(400, CGFLOAT_MAX) 
                                                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

it always crash when showing the label.

I don't know why but I replace it with a UITextView and problem solved.

Does anyone know any reason for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
float desiredHeight = 50.0;
NSString *yourText = @\"This is some\nmultiline text\nthat you want to fit in your frame.\";
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(30.0, 30.0, 250.0, desiredHeight);
int originalFontSize = 30; // let's say
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:originalFontSize];

frame.size.height = 3000.0; // just make sure it's big enough
CGSize result = [yourText sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:frame.size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
int newFontSize = (desiredHeight / result.height) * (float)originalFontSize;
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:newFontSize];
label.numberOfLines = 0;

label.text = yourText;

[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Try this and adjust font . also adjust the line number. it may rectify ur problem i hope

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better to make something like this:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 0.0)];
[label setText: @"your text"];
[label sizeToFit];

CGRect labelFrame = label.frame;
labelFrame.size.height = label.contentSize.height;
label.frame            = labelFrame;

[self.view addSubview: label];
```

Now you can add text and its height will calculate by xcode